# Strategy to reduce duplicate code in many similar modules

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, modules

**The Situation**

I have created some code in the form of modules that each represent a medical questionnaire (I'm calling them `Catalog`s). Each different questionnaire has its own module as they may differ slightly in their content and associated calculations, but are essentially made up of simple questions that have boolean/numeric possible responses. [Here](http://www.janssenmedicalinformation.ca/assets/pdf/HarveyBradshaw_English.pdf) is an example.

These `Catalog` modules are included in an `Entry` class that collects responses matching the question names. Each questionnaire is transformed into a `DEFINITION` which is used in the `Entry` to do things like:

- Validate inputs
- Check completeness
- Calculate scoring

There are 2 examples for reference at the bottom that illustrate the problem of duplication... much of the code is similar but not *exactly* the same.

**The Problem**

There is a lot of duplication here, but I'm not sure about the best strategy to remove it. There are a few things that make it difficult for this particular problem and make me lean towards accepting some duplication as opposed to a system that is too strict to work. The system needs to remain flexible enough to accommodate currently unknown medical questionnaires of a similar nature so I need to be careful (the reason I've gone with a `Module` system so far)

Here are some examples:

- Each `Catalog` can have slightly different scoring requirements and custom grouping of questions that represent one "score"
- Potentially many `Catalog`s are included in an `Entry` class and can't step on each other
- Some `Catalog`s incorporate things like "Current Weight" for calculations, breaking the 1-5 or 1-10 paradigm and not fitting very nicely into simple `sum` reductions.
- One `Catalog` requires a week of previous entries in order to be valid, a sort of weird custom validation.

**The Question:**

What strategies might be employed here to reduce duplication overall? I'm not looking for tweaks cut out a few lines from these specific examples. Implementation cost is a consideration.

Possibilities:

- Put some of this into a database (sounds pretty good, but I think the cost of implementation could be high)
- I fear there could be room for improvement in my metaprogramming here, perhaps there are better ways to accomplish this through some dynamic method creation or other voodoo.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/theworkerant/3a074d5d2a642ded1b96) and inline below:

```
module HbiCatalog
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  DEFINITION = [

    ### General Well-Being
    [{
      # 0 Very Well
      # 1 Slightly below par
      # 2 Poor
      # 3 Very poor
      # 4 Terrible

      name: :general_wellbeing,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "very_well", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "slightly_below_par", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "poor", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "very_poor", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 4, label: "terrible", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Abdominal Pain
    [{
      # 0 None
      # 1 Mild
      # 2 Moderate
      # 3 Severe

      name: :ab_pain,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "none", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "mild", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "moderate", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "severe", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Number of Liquid/Soft Stools for the Day
    [{
      name: :stools,
      kind: :number,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: nil, meta_label: nil, helper: "stools_daily"}
      ]
    }],

    ### Abdominal Mass
    [{
      # 0 None
      # 1 Dubious
      # 2 Definite
      # 3 Definite and Tender

      name: :ab_mass,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "none", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "dubious", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "definite", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "definite_and_tender", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Complications (1 point each)
    # Arthralgia
    # Uveitis
    # Erythema nodosum
    # Aphthous ulcers
    # Pyoderma gangrenosum
    # Anal fissure
    # New fistula
    # Abscess

    [
      {
        name: :complication_arthralgia,
        kind: :checkbox
      },
      {
        name: :complication_uveitis,
        kind: :checkbox
      },
      {
        name: :complication_erythema_nodosum,
        kind: :checkbox
      },
      {
        name: :complication_aphthous_ulcers,
        kind: :checkbox
      },
      {
        name: :complication_anal_fissure,
        kind: :checkbox
      },
      {
        name: :complication_fistula,
        kind: :checkbox
      },
      {
        name: :complication_abscess,
        kind: :checkbox
      }
    ]
  ]

  SCORE_COMPONENTS  = %i( general_wellbeing ab_pain stools ab_mass complications )
  QUESTIONS         = DEFINITION.map{|questions| questions.map{|question| question[:name] }}.flatten
  COMPLICATIONS     = DEFINITION[4].map{|question| question[:name] }.flatten

  included do |base_class|
    validate :hbi_response_ranges
    def hbi_response_ranges
      ranges = [
        [:general_wellbeing, [*0..4]],
        [:ab_pain, [*0..3]],
        [:stools, [*0..50]],
        [:ab_mass, [*0..3]],
      ]

      ranges.each do |range|
        response = hbi_responses.detect{|r| r.name.to_sym == range[0]}
        if response and not range[1].include?(response.value)
          # TODO add catalog namespace here
          self.errors.messages[:responses] ||= {}
          self.errors.messages[:responses][range[0]] = "Not within allowed values"
        end
      end

    end

    validate :hbi_response_booleans
    def hbi_response_booleans
      HbiCatalog::COMPLICATIONS.each do |name|
        response = hbi_responses.detect{|r| r.name.to_sym == name}

        if response and not [0,1].include? response.value.to_i
          self.errors.messages[:responses] ||= {}
          self.errors.messages[:responses][name.to_sym] = "Must be true or false"
        end
      end
    end

  end

  def hbi_responses
    responses.select{|r| r.catalog == "hbi"}
  end

  # def valid_hbi_entry?
  #   return false unless last_6_entries.count == 6
  #   !last_6_entries.map{|e| e.filled_hbi_entry?}.include?(false)
  # end
  def filled_hbi_entry?
    (QUESTIONS - hbi_responses.reduce([]) {|accu, response| (accu << response.name.to_sym) if response.name}) == []
  end

  def complete_hbi_entry?
    filled_hbi_entry?
  end

  # def setup_hbi_scoring
  # end

  def hbi_complications_score
    COMPLICATIONS.reduce(0) do |sum, question_name|
      sum + (self.send("hbi_#{question_name}").to_i)
    end.to_f
  end


end
```

---

```
module Rapid3Catalog
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  DEFINITION = [

    ### Over the last week were you able to.. ###
    ### Dress yourself, including tying shoelaces and doing buttons?
    [{
      name: :dress_yourself,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Get in and out of bed?
    [{
      name: :get_in_out_of_bed,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Lift a full glass of water to your mouth?
    [{
      name: :lift_full_glass,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Walk outdoors on flat ground?
    [{
      name: :walk_outdoors,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Wash and dry your entire body?
    [{
      name: :wash_and_dry_yourself,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Bend down to pick up clothing from the floor?
    [{
      name: :bend_down,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Turn regular faucets on and off?
    [{
      name: :turn_faucet,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Get in and out of a car, bus, train, or airplane?
    [{
      name: :enter_exit_vehicles,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Walk two miles or three kilometers, if you wish?
    [{
      name: :walk_two_miles,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Participate in recreational activities and sports as you would like, if you wish?
    [{
      name: :play_sports,
      kind: :select,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### !!! RAPID3 FORM SAYS: questions K-M have been found to be informative, but are not scored formally
    ### !!! So they are commented out
    # ### Get a good nightâ€™s sleep?
    # [{
    #   name: :sleep_well,
    #   section: 10,
    #   kind: :select,
    #   inputs: [
    #     {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 1.1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #   ]
    # }],
    #
    # ### Deal with feelings of anxiety or being nervous?
    # [{
    #   name: :deal_with_anxiety,
    #   section: 11,
    #   kind: :select,
    #   inputs: [
    #     {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #   ]
    # }],
    #
    # ### Deal with feelings of depression or feeling blue?
    # [{
    #   name: :deal_with_depression,
    #   section: 12,
    #   kind: :select,
    #   inputs: [
    #     {value: 0, label: "no_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 1, label: "some_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 2, label: "much_difficulty", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #     {value: 3, label: "unable", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
    #   ]
    # }],

    ### How much pain have you had because of your condition OVER THE PAST WEEK?
    [{
      name: :pain_tolerance,
      kind: :range,
      step: 0.5,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0.0, label: "no_pain", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 10.0, label: "maximum_pain", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],

    ### Considering all the ways in which illness and health conditions may affect you at this time, please indicate below how you are doing:
    [{
      name: :global_estimate,
      kind: :range,
      step: 0.5,
      inputs: [
        {value: 0.0, label: "very_well", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
        {value: 10.0, label: "very_poorly", meta_label: "", helper: nil},
      ]
    }],
  ]

  SCORING_INDEX =  [0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.7, 4.0, 4.3, 4.7, 5.0, 5.3, 5.7, 6.0, 6.3, 6.7, 7.0, 7.3, 7.7, 8.0, 8.3, 8.7, 9.0, 9.3, 9.7, 10]

  SCORE_COMPONENTS     = %i( functional_status pain_tolerance global_estimate )

  QUESTIONS            = DEFINITION.map{|questions| questions.map{|question| question[:name] }}.flatten
  FUNCTIONAL_QUESTIONS = (QUESTIONS - [:pain_tolerance, :global_estimate])

  included do |base_class|
    validate :response_ranges
    def response_ranges
      ranges = [
        [:pain_tolerance, (0..10).step(0.5).to_a],
        [:global_estimate, (0..10).step(0.5).to_a],
      ]

      FUNCTIONAL_QUESTIONS.each{|q| ranges << [q, [*0..3] ]}

      ranges.each do |range|
        response = rapid3_responses.select{|r| r.name.to_sym == range[0]}.first
        if response and not range[1].include?(response.value)
          # self.errors.add "responses.#{range[0]}", "Not within allowed values"
          self.errors.messages[:responses] ||= {}
          self.errors.messages[:responses][range[0]] = "Not within allowed values"
        end
      end

    end

  end

  def rapid3_responses
    responses.select{|r| r.catalog == "rapid3"}
  end

  def filled_rapid3_entry?
    (QUESTIONS - responses.reduce([]) {|accu, response| (accu << response.name.to_sym) if response.name}) == []
  end

  def complete_rapid3_entry?
    filled_rapid3_entry?
  end

  # def setup_rapid3_scoring
  # end

  # def finalize_rapid3_scoring(score)
  #   RAPID3_SCORING_INDEX[score.round-1] # "weight" the final score
  # end

  def rapid3_functional_status_score
    score = FUNCTIONAL_QUESTIONS.reduce(0) do |sum, question_name|
      sum + self.send("rapid3_#{question_name}")
    end
    SCORING_INDEX[score-1]
  end

  def rapid3_pain_tolerance_score
    self.send(:rapid3_pain_tolerance)
  end

  def rapid3_global_estimate_score
    self.send(:rapid3_global_estimate)
  end


end
```

Answer (score 2):

You mention in your description that `Entry` will do three different things:

- Validate inputs
- Check completeness
- Calculate scoring

This violates the single responsibility principle. `Entry` does too much! I suggest a system where `Entry` is *just* an accumulation of answers with a general API to retrieve questions and their answers. Ideally it would use some meta-programming to make the code simpler and self-documenting.

```ruby
class HBI
  include Questionnaire

  select(:general_wellbeing) do |s|
    s.option(:no_difficulty,      0, :optional => :stuff)
    s.option(:slightly_below_par, 1, :optional => :stuff)
    # etc
  end
end

hbi = HBI.new
hbi.answer(:general_wellbeing, 1, :optional => :stuff)
hbi.general_wellbeing # => 1 or for example an Answer object
```

Validating can largely be avoided, because in `Entry` you define which values are acceptable as answers. Simply raise an error in `Entry#answer` when receiving a non-sensical value (such as 10). You still need to check for completeness, though.

A validator object can validate an `Entry`. You could use some more meta-programming here to avoid repetition or use a library like [scrivener](https://github.com/soveran/scrivener).

```ruby
class HBIValidator
  def initialize(entry)
    @entry = entry
  end

  def validate
    assert_presence(:well_being)
    # etc
  end
end

validator = HBIValidator.new(hbi)
validator.valid? # => true or false
```

A scoring object can then score an `Entry`. Again you could use some meta-programming here to avoid repetition.

Thinking about validation more, it actually is hardly necessary. Entry defines exactly which the exact

```
scorer = HBIScorer.new(hbi)
scorer.score # => 10 or for example a Score object.
```

A good term to google for if you want some help with the meta-programming is [DSL (Domain Specific Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

Comment: Thanks @britishtea, I hear you on these points. However, most of the scoring logic actually *is* moved out of the catalog already (in a `CatalogScore` module), only a few placeholder methods are left for the idiosyncrasies of specific catalog. Also, this doesn't really help me cut down on duplication, as I would just be moving things around for each catalog module.

Comment: Also, you're right a DSL might be a good fit here... but the question remains, what exactly would that DSL do? And how does it help me cut down on duplication while still dealing with weirdness of each particular catalog?

Comment: The DSL will take away all the boilerplate code that you currently have. I haven't inspected the example code very closely, but from what I can tell is there is a lot of duplicate boilerplate code mixed with the logic that is actually different. I will update the answer to illustrate this better.

Comment: Also, a simpler example or a clearer example would greatly help to answer your question better.

Comment: It's single responsibility *principle*, not "problem" ;-)